# PIVOTing variable number of rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm currently attempting to PIVOT some rows to columns. The problem is that I don't always know how many rows will be available. Let's look at an example:

```
Values_Table                         Columns_Table
------------                         -----------
ID                                   ID
ColumnsTableID                       GroupID
Value                                ColumnName
```

RESULTS"

```
Columns_Table
---------------
ID   |   GroupID   |   ColumnName
---------------------------------     
0        1             Cats
1        1             Dogs
2        1             Birds
3        2             Pontiac
4        2             Ford
5        3             Trex
6        3             Raptor
7        3             Triceratops
8        3             Kentrosaurus
```

SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE of a STATIC pivot. I am trying to achieve a dynamic pivot - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2be82/1

So, here is my dilemma: I want to be able to pivot an unknown number of columns based on, in this scenario, the GroupID.

I want to be able to PIVOT, for example, all the rows in GroupID 3 into columns. I would need to do this without knowing how many rows are in groupID 3.

The design of the database is set in stone, so I can't do anything about that. All I can do is work with what I have :(

So, that said- does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this task of PIVOTing an unknown number of rows into columns based on, in this example, the groupID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not going to know the values ahead of time, then you will need to look at using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).  This will create a SQL String that will be executed, this is required because the list of columns must be known when the query is run.

The code will be similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @groupid as int

set @groupid = 3

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(GroupName) 
                    from Columns_Table
                    where groupid = @groupid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              SELECT B.GroupName, A.Value
                , row_number() over(partition by a.ColumnsTableID
                                    order by a.Value) seq
              FROM Values_Table AS A 
              INNER JOIN Columns_Table AS B 
                ON A.ColumnsTableID = B.ID
              where b.groupid = '+cast(@groupid as varchar(10))+' 
            ) p
            pivot 
            (
                min(P.Value)
                for P.GroupName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2be82/3). For groupid of 3, then the result will be:

```
|   KENTROSAURUS |     RAPTOR |     TREX |    TRICERATOPS |
| whatisthiseven | Itsaraptor | Jurassic | landbeforetime |
|         (null) |       zomg |     Park |         (null) |
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much for your answer =D As always, spot on!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you think of a way that this could be put into a temporary table without knowing what the column names are ahead of time?

Comment: @user1548103 You could look at using select into you new table.