# EAV table to flat table

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

Say I have a table `eav` like this ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15b03/15)):

```
| Person_ID | PAttribute_ID | Value         |
| 1         | 1             | Flat Street 1 |
| 1         | 2             | 634-5789      |
```

And want to create a query that returns all attributes as a flat table (e.g. to export to a spreadsheet)

Is there a better way than just manually left joining for all the attributes? Like this:

```
SELECT id , address.Value AS adressV, telephone.Value as telephoneV
FROM person
LEFT JOIN eav AS address ON address.Person_ID = person.id AND address.PAttribute_ID = 1
LEFT JOIN eav AS telephone ON telephone.Person_ID = person.id AND telephone.PAttribute_ID = 2;
```

With 2 attributes that's feasible, with 50 attributes you get an un-understandable query.

Comment: I think no, there's no better way of such an export. I'm now working with MantisBT, it has a similarly designed table of custom fields, and yes, left joins everywhere.

Comment: You could look into some dynamic sql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875796/pivoting-variable-number-of-rows-to-columns