# Is it possible to name SQL result columns from rows in another table? (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Basically I have users with a dynamic attributes table. Simplified:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
 id  |                  email                   
-----+------------------------------------------
  1 | example@example.com


SELECT * FROM user_attributes;
 id |      name      
----+----------------
  1 | Salutation
  2 | Given Name
  3 | Surname
  4 | Alias
  5 | Address
  6 | Address 2
  7 | Address 3
  8 | City
  9 | Region
....

SELECT * FROM user_attribute_values;
 client_id | attribute_id | value 
-----------+--------------+-------
```

What I'm looking to do is a SELECT that would return columns user_id, city, region where city & region are not empty.

The reason for the user_attributes table is one may want to store any number of custom fields about the user, and it's impossible to know beforehand what they will be to create them as columns of the user table.

Comment: As I (perhaps inadequately) explained, I have no way to know what the columns will be beforehand. user_attributes is dynamic, and it's absolutely impossible to pre-determine what a particular user may want. Do they want to track hair color? The type of car the user drives? His favorite snack? Otherwise I would agree and would have designed it differently.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work in Postgresql, but try looking into dynamic pivot table. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875796/pivoting-variable-number-of-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT u.id, a_city.value AS city, a_region.value AS region
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN user_attribute_values a_city ON a_city.client_id = u.id AND a_city.attribute_id = 8
 INNER JOIN user_attribute_values a_region ON a_region.client_id = u.id AND a_region.attribute_id = 9
 WHERE LENGTH(a_city.value) > 0
   AND LENGTH(a_region.value) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is based on a **principal misunderstanding** of the inner workings of Postgres and [EAV designs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20759/3684).

If you don't have hundreds of different fields or a dynamic set of attribute types, use a **single table with all columns** - except for [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Columns without value are filled with `NULL`.
Null storage is *very cheap*, occupying **1 bit** per column in the table for the null bitmap, typically allocated in units of 8 bytes to cover 64 columns. See:

- [How much disk-space is needed to store a NULL value using postgresql DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229805/how-much-disk-space-is-needed-to-store-a-null-value-using-postgresql-db/7654497#7654497)

A separate row for a **single** additional attribute occupies *at least* an additional **36 bytes**.

```
4  bytes item identifier
23 bytes heap tuple header
1  byte  padding
8  bytes minimum row data size
```

Typically more, due to padding and additional overhead.

There would have to be hundreds of different, sparsely populated columns before such an unwieldy EAV design could pay - and [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) or [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) in Postgres 9.4 would be superior solutions for *that*. There is hardly any room in between for your design, and *if* there was, you'd probably be using an [`enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) for the type.

At the same time, queries are more complicated and expensive. We're in a tight spot here.

Instead use a table layout like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   users_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , salutation text
 , given_name text
 , surname text
 , alias text
 ... (many) more columns
);

CREATE TABLE address (
   address_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , users_id int REFERENCES users
 , city text  -- or separate TABLE city incl region_id etc. ...
 , region_id int REFERENCES region
 , address  text
 ... (many) more columns
);
```

Closely related answer with more advice:

- [SQL : Create a full record from 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186533/sql-create-a-full-record-from-2-tables/25188471#25188471)

Answer (score 0):

```
select    client_id,
          min(case when attribute_id = 8 then value else '0' end) as city,
          min(case when attribute_id = 9 then value else '0' end) as region
from      user_attribute_values
group by  clientid
having    min(case when attribute_id = 8 then value else '0' end) <> '0'
       or min(case when attribute_id = 9 then value else '0' end) <> '0'
```

This will show clients with a city or region value. If you want only clients with BOTH such attributes, in the having clause, change the OR to an AND.