# How to get unique result with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables 1) `Users` and 2) `Images`.

```
Users table

id  name     
1   xyz  
2   abc


Images table

id  path    
1   ~/img/12.jpg
1   ~/img/34.jpg
2   ~/img/de.jpg
2   ~/img/rt.jpg
```

So now when I write the query:

```
select id, name, path
from users
    left join images on images.id = users.id
where id =1
```

Then it will give me output like:

```
id  name path
1   xyz  ~/img/12.jpg
1   xyz  ~/img/34.jpg
```

But I need the output like:

```
   id   name   path1        path2
    1   xyz  ~/img/12.jpg  ~/img/34.jpg
```

How can I get this?

Comment: This is called a crosstab. Take a look at the numerous examples on SO. An important question is: are there only ever two columns or can there be many?

Comment: If the number of columns is fixed, then you can use a SQL pivot.  If not, then [it might get ugly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875796/pivoting-variable-number-of-rows-to-columns).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid fixed 2 columns

Comment: @Deepak below answer might satisfy your criteria..check once

Comment: You're query is invalid... (Id in select list and where clause ambiguous.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your output we can achieve using Cross Apply and Pivot

```
declare @users TABLE 
    (id   INT,      varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO @users
    (id, name)
VALUES

    (1, 'xyz'),
    (2, 'abc')
;


declare @images  TABLE 
    (id int, path varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO @images
    (id, path)
VALUES

    (1, '~/img/12.jpg'),
    (1, '~/img/34.jpg'),
    (2, '~/img/de.jpg'),
    (2, '~/img/rt.jpg')
;
select * from (
select s.id, 
s.name , 
images.path,
COL + CAST(row_number()over(PARTITION BY s.ID ORDER BY COL) AS VARCHAR) RN 
from @users s 
left join @images images  
on images.id=s.id
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('path',path))CS(Col,val)
    where s.id =1)P
    PIVOT (MAX(PATH) FOR RN IN ([path1],[path2]))P
```

Comment: Thank you. But its too long.,

Comment: because  I have given with the table data  that's the reason it is looking like that more over performance wise it will give faster results..@deepak

Comment: Ok. let me execute it again.

Comment: It works good. But suppose if i want the all data  `without s.id=1` then how can i do it? i have removed the `where s.id=1` then it gives me null in path1 and path2

Comment: @deepak I tried with your data what ever you have posted by removing where condition it is not showing any null values...just execute my whole code including sample data

Comment: Why varchar instead of integer for the id columns?

Comment: it's a sample data..anyway I have modified thanks @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

It is easy when it is fixed to 2 paths

```
;WITH paths AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY path) AS Seq FROM Images
)
SELECT 
  *
  (SELECT path FROM paths WHERE id = u.id AND Seq = 1) Path1, 
  (SELECT path FROM paths WHERE id = u.id AND Seq = 2) Path2 
FROM Users u 
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY` for min and max path:

```
select u.id, u.name, min(i.path), max(i.path)
from users u
    left join images i on i.id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
```

Works well as long as just one or two paths for a user.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Group by like

```
select id, name , path from users left join images on images.id=users.id
where id =1 group by id
```