# SQL Server 2016: Turn multiple lines into columns with the different iterations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that has many InsuranceNo's for unique MemberIDs. If there are more than one InsuranceNo, I want the InsuranceNo's to shift to a column, so in the end there is one line per MemberID, with all the iterations of that ID's InsuranceNo's as a Column.

```
MemberID       InsuranceNo
--------------------------
123456            dser
124571            jklh
123456            abcd
```

I want it to look like this:

```
MemberID       InsuranceNo1             InsuranceNo2
-----------------------------------------------------
123456            dser                  abcd
124571            jklh
```

Thank you!

Comment: `row_number` and `case` expressions

Comment: how many insurance numbers can a user have/

Comment: an unlimited amount of insurance numbers per unique memberid

Comment: search `dynamic pivot`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875796/pivoting-variable-number-of-rows-to-columns

Comment: I might be looking at this wrong, but the dynamic pivot would mean that instead of just having a column 1,2,3...the columns would be labeled dser, jklh, etc.  That wouldn't work here because there would be several thousand columns.

Comment: I won't know the column names ahead of time.  If there are three instances of an InsuranceNo for one Member ID, then I want three of the columns (InsuranceNo1, InsuranceNo2, etc) populated with the three instances.  The resulting table would have one line per memberid

Comment: Do you know the max number of InsuranceNos ahead of time? Or does that need to be dynamic?

Comment: I will not, it will change

Comment: Assuming you succeed in writing a dynamic pivot, how will you consume the results?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option... Just change **"YourTable"** to your actual table name.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select MemberID
              ,Item     = concat(''InsuranceNo'',row_number() over (Partition By MemberID Order By (Select NULL)))
              ,Value    = InsuranceNo
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select ','+QuoteName(concat('InsuranceNo',ColNr)) 
                                               From (Select Distinct ColNr=row_number() over (Partition By MemberID Order By (Select NULL)) from YourTable ) A  
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
MemberID    InsuranceNo1    InsuranceNo2
123456      dser            abcd
124571      jklh            NULL
```

**If it helps wrap your head around PIVOT**, the SQL Generated looks like this:

```
Select *
 From (
        Select MemberID
              ,Item     = concat('InsuranceNo',row_number() over (Partition By MemberID Order By (Select NULL)))
              ,Value    = InsuranceNo
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ([InsuranceNo1],[InsuranceNo2]) ) p
```

Comment: @ErinRager Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a dynamic cross tab to the dynamic pivot. I find the syntax far less obtuse and it is super easy if you need to add additional columns. Here is I would go about tackling this. Of course in your case you don't need a temp table because you have an actual table to use.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    MemberID int
    , InsuranceNo varchar(10)
)

insert #Something values
(123456, 'dser')
, (124571, 'jklh')
, (123456, 'abcd')

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MemberID order by InsuranceNo) as RowNum
        from #Something
    )
    select MemberID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by MemberID order by MemberID';

with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then InsuranceNo end) as InsuranceNo' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by MemberID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)
select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```